# Cannot download datasets from tfds

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, generative-adversarial-network

I cannot download the Celeb_A dataset for StarGAN. I got an error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/download/downloader.py
> in _assert_status(response)
> 305   if response.status_code != 200:
> 306     raise DownloadError('Failed to get url {}. HTTP code: {}.'.format(
> --> 307         response.url, response.status_code))
>
> DownloadError: Failed to get url
> https://doc-0s-84-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/mmcut2ct3jgin059v1ghnj42u1sh94vq/1663839525000/13182073909007362810/*/0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM?e=download&uuid=6034c829-29c2-423d-b5dc-92844dd6abcd.
> HTTP code: 429.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue (http code: 429) with download of celeba dataset when I called

```
tfds.load('celeb_a', data_dir='./', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
```

I just found working solution to download data [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/fairness-indicators/blob/master/g3doc/tutorials/Fairness_Indicators_TFCO_CelebA_Case_Study.ipynb#scrollTo=zCSemFST0b89).

```
tfds.builder('celeb_a', data_dir='./', version='2.0.1')
celeb_a_builder = celeb_a_builder.download_and_prepare()
```

It downloads data in tfrecord format and you can get tensorflow dataset this way

```
celeb_a_data = celeb_a_builder.as_dataset()
```

I hope it helps.

It is stated in documentation to [tfds.load](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load) function that it is a convenience method for

```
tfds.builder(...),
builder.download_and_prepare(...)
builder.as_dataset(...)
```

so the result should be same at the end.